# Преобразование string в DateTime (List)

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема при изменении формата переменной.
У меня есть класс:

```
public class Parsing
{
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

И сам код:

```
string line;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"Путь");
List<Parsing> csv = new List<Parsing>();
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var csvRow = line.Split(';').Skip(1).ToList();

    var objList = new Parsing
    {
        FIO = (csvRow[0]),
        Date = DateTime.Parse(csvRow[1]),

    };
    csv.Add(objList);

}
```

Когда я пытаюсь, изменить поле "Date" на формат даты, то мне выдает ошибку:
*"Данная строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime. Обнаружено неизвестное слово, начинающееся с индекса 0."*
Я понимаю, что это связанно с тем, что у меня заголовок имеет тип string, а уже поля имеют формат Datetime, но как мне это обойти, я думал, что .Skip(1) мне поможет?

```
Вот пример CSV-файла:
Дата рождения
12.12.1912
01.01.1901
```

Comment: Перед циклом `while` вызовите один раз `file.ReadLine()`, чтобы пропустить заголовок.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался, помогло.

Comment: Небольшое замечание. В тот век, когда файлы свободно передаются по интернету, рассчитывать что все даны будут в формате текущего системного языка не стоит. Вместо этого лучше явно указывать либо формат даты (`DateTime.ParseExact`) - либо передавать `CultureInfo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведенном коде *Skip* вызывается на результате разделения строки.

То есть, в данном случае пропускается один *столбец*. а не строка с заголовком.

Чтобы пропустить строку заголовка, нужно либо считать эту строку один раз в холостую, не обрабатывая ее.

Либо воспользоваться методом [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), который возвращает `IEnumerable<string>` и применить к нему *Skip*.

Например так:

```
List<Parsing> csv = (from line in File.ReadLines(@"Путь").Skip(1)
                     let csvRow = line.Split(';').Skip(1).ToList()
                     select new Parsing
                     {
                         FIO = (csvRow[0]),
                         Date = DateTime.Parse(csvRow[1]),
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: Какой способ будет наиболее правильным? Я подозреваю второй (:

Comment: @Tibomso, на самом деле они примерно одинаковы. Возможно с _File.ReadLines_ чуть проще читается. но суть одна и так же